# MongoDB element on nested schemas and return only that element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, schema

i have this Schema for a simple twitter app

```
const userSchema = new Schema ({
    loginInfo: {
        username: String,
        email: String,
        password: String 
    },
    tweets: [{
        content: String,
        likes: Number,
        comments: [{
            owner: String,
            content: String,
            likes: Number
        }]
    }],
    followers: [String],
    following: [String]
})
```

and i want to make endpoint that return only the tweet that has the same **_id** that has been given as a params on the URL ..
I made that solution below and its working correctly but i believe there is a much better solution than this ..

```
const handleTweet = (User) => (req,res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let theTweet = [];
    User.findOne({ "tweets._id": id})
    .then(user => {
        user.tweets.forEach(tweet => {
            if(tweet._id.toString() === id)
                return theTweet.push(tweet)
        })
        res.json(theTweet)
    })
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
}

module.exports = handleTweet;
```

One more question : **Is it better to make nested schemas like this or making a different models for each schema (in this case schema for User and another one for Tweets) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the tweets into a different collection since you are querying based on that, and then you can use [autopopulate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate) when you need it.

Also instead of the foreach you could use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Hope this helps!